# need help understanding and fixing a NumberFormatException and an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I have a homework assignment where I need to implement two methods that can flatten two 2d arrays. One of type int and the other of type string. When I run my program I get two exceptions, a `NumberFormatException` when I try to print the String array and an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I try to print the int array. The only methods I am allowed to change are the  methods named flatten. I have two problems. The first is that I do not understand why I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or how to fix it. The second is that  while I do understand why I am getting a NumberFormatException, I am not sure how to fix it.

```
public class Flatten {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        int[][] x = {
                {},
                {1,},
                {1, 2,},
                {1, 2, 3,},
                {1, 2, 3, 4,},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,},
                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,},
        };
        print(flatten(x));

        String[][] y = {
                {"if", "else", "switch",},
                {"while", "do while", "for",},
                {"break", "continue",},
                {"*", "/", "%", "+", "-",},
                {">", ">=", "<=", "<", "==", "!=",},
                {"&&", "||", "!",},
                {"<<", ">>", ">>>", "&", "|", "^", "~",},
        };
        print(flatten(y));
    }

    /**
     * Prints a "flattened" 1d-array of ints.
     *
     * @param a the flattened array to print
     */
    static void print(int[] a) {
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         System.out.print("{ ");
         for (int j = 0, k = a[i]; j < k; j++)
            System.out.print(a[++i] + ", ");
         System.out.println("}");
      }
   }

    /**
     * Prints a "flattened" 1d-array of String objects.
     *
     * @param a the flattened array to print
     */
      static void print(String[] a) {
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         System.out.print("{ ");
         for (int j = 0, k = Integer.parseInt(a[i]); j < k; j++)
            System.out.print("\"" + a[++i] + "\", ");
         System.out.println("}");
      }
   }

    /**
     * TBI (To Be Implemented)...
     * <p>
     * This method "flattens" a 2-dimensional int-array
     * into a 1-dimensional int-array.  The algorithm
     * for flattening the 2d array is defined by code
     * in the print(int[]) method.
     *
     * @param x 2-dimensional int-array to "flatten"
     * @return the "flattened" 1-dimensional int-array
     */
    static int[] flatten(int[][] x) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            count += x[i].length;
        }
        int[] arr = new int[count];
        int index = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < x[row].length; col++) {
                arr[index] = x[row][col];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    /**
     * TBI (To Be Implemented)...
     * <p>
     * This method "flattens" a 2-dimensional String-array
     * into a 1-dimensional String-array.  The algorithm
     * for flattening the 2d array is defined by code
     * in the print(String[]) method.
     *
     * @param x 2-dimensional String-array to "flatten"
     * @return the "flattened" 1-dimensional String-array
     */
    static String[] flatten(String[][] x) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            count += x[i].length;
        }
        String[] arr = new String[count];
        int index = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
                arr[index] = x[row][column];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

I expect the output to look like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQGhx.png

Any ideas on how to fix these errors and avoid them in the future would be appreciated.

Edit: Here's where the exceptions are being thrown
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq5MO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIQ4B.png

Comment: why do you have an extra comma `{1,}` ?

Comment: it's how my prof wrote the code. Everything except for the flatten methods were written by him.

Comment: Please post you errors otherwise we have no idea where there are being thrown

Comment: Is it that you are looking to convert the two 2-Dimensional arrays into one 1-Dimensional array with all the elements from both arrays?

Comment: Sorry forgot too add the exceptions, edited my post. I'm trying to convert the two 2d arrays into two separate 1d arrays. When they're printed using my profs methods I guess they just look like its big array

Comment: In `static void print(String[] a)` why are you using `parseInt` ?

Comment: That's part of the code that was provided by my prof. I do not believe I'm allowed to change it

Comment: So my problem is that I’m not properly flattening the array?

Comment: There are parts of the code that makes no sense as in why is there extra commas in the `int[][]` array with no elements in the last position and the `parseInt(...)` in the `print(...)` function for the `String` array is not valid for the elements that it contains.

Comment: Didn't your professor teach you how to use debug in IDE before giving the assignment ? If not, I would advise to study on debugging code on your own first and if that still does not help then only seek help from SO community.

Comment: I think the print method is the problem. Your flatten method is fine.

Comment: Is the parseInt causing all of the trouble when I try to print the String array?

Comment: @DominicA That is one of the problem since none of the elements in the `String` array are integers (cannot be converted).

Comment: My prof has not taught us anything about how to use debug in IDE. Thank you for the advice, I'll look into studying it.

Comment: @OmariCelestine I guess I'll try to rewrite my profs print methods and hope he does not mind that too much. Thanks for the help